# Pipe to program email duplication issue

Tags: php, cpanel, exim

We have Cpanel with forwarding emails using "Pipe to Program" feature.

Forwarders example:

```
Email Address           Forward To  
email.1@domain.com      |/home/user/forwarder/forward.php    
email.2@domain.com      |/home/user/forwarder/forward.php
```

forward.php:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
$forwarders = [
    'email.1@domain.com' => ['email.1@gmail.com'],
    'email.2@domain.com' => ['email.2@gmail.com']
];

$recipients = $parseHeader['to'];
$to = [];
foreach($recipients as $recipient){
    if(isset($forwarders[$recipient])){
        foreach($forwarders[$recipient] as $forwarder){
            $to[] = $forwarder;
        }            
    }
}

//Send one email with emails in $to
```

Let's say I send an email to both 'email.1@domain.com' and 'email.2@domain.com' the above script will produce `$to` data:

```
[
    'email.1@gmail.com',
    'email.2@gmail.com'
]
```

We try to create a forwarded email that contains the same recipients but with the forwarded emails so the same email will be sent to 'email.1@gmail.com' and 'email.2@gmail.com'.

The issue is that both recipients receive 2 identical emails and if there is 'email.3@domain.com' it will be sent 3 times ..etc.

We tried to send an email with `To: email.1@domain.com` and `CC: email.2@domain.com` but the same thing happened.

Scenario:

1. An email is sent to 'email.1@domain.com' and 'email.2@domain.com'.
2. Forwarders trigger 'email.1@domain.com' and execute the script that sends an email to 'email.1@gmail.com' and 'email.2@gmail.com'
3. Forwarders trigger 'email.2@domain.com' and execute the script that sends an email to 'email.1@gmail.com' and 'email.2@gmail.com'

Is it possible to avoid this issue?

Comment: Confused as to why you're even using PHP here. Just use the native forwarding mechanism.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Unfortunately, our hands are tied here. The website is hosted on Amazon EC2 instance and they block port 25. All email senders need to be verified first. That's the only available method. Lambada functions and s3 method is the same I think and requires more work to understand and apply. I think it sends one email only in this case.

Comment: If they block port 25 then how does this script work?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Port 587 TLS SMPT

Comment: Port 587... on what machine? Are you proxying messages to yourself? All this could just be done in Exim.

Comment: @AlexHowansky On the same instance using SES service with credentials and port 587 using PHPMailer

Comment: @AlexHowansky The port is not the only problem. The sender's email must be verified. I.e. `FROM: sender@gmail.com` `TO: email.1@domain.com` with normal forward will become `FROM: sender@gmail.com` `TO: email.1@gmail.com`  and we won't receive this one because `sender@gmail.com` is not verified in SES for our domain.

Comment: The `foreach($forwarders[$recipient] as $forwarder)` in the code you have currently shown us makes no sense - `$forwarders[$recipient]` is a string value.

Comment: @CBroe My fault it's an array. I updated the code.

Comment: Still can't make sense of your explanation. Your step 2 in your scenario you outlined at the bottom, is forwarding that mail _to_ `email.1@domain.com` to your script there. Not sure how this would now send an email to `email.2@gmail.com` as well - when the latter is not even contained in your `$forwarders['email.1@domain.com']` entry ...?

Comment: @CBroe Because we loop through the recipients' emails for example `To: email.1@domain.com,email.2@domain.com`  will become `To: email.1@gmail.com,email.2@gmail.com`

Comment: _"Because we loop through the recipients' emails"_ - but there _is_ only one recipient in step2 of your example scenario ...?

Comment: @CBroe There are 2 recipients in this example `email.1@domain.com` and `email.2@domain.com` with this script when it loops it will send 2 emails to both emails `email.1@gmail.com` and `email.2@gmail.com`

Comment: You said "Forwarders trigger 'email.1@domain.com'" in your step 2, so I would assume that means you piped ONE email that had ONE recipient, to your script there. If it meant something else, then please explain.

Comment: @CBroe If there is one recipient there is no problem. When there are multiple recipients with our domain piped to the script this issue happens. The example shows that the email was sent to 2 recipients each of them has a pipe to the script.

Comment: So this is _one_ incoming email, that is addressed to _both_ recipients at the same time (how exactly - one CC/BCC?), and because you have set up those pipes for each one of the recipients, the same script then runs twice, each time with _two_ emails as "input" - is that the correct description of the scenario? If the script runs twice, then I suppose you don't have much of an option other than to "queue" your response mails somewhere first, so that you can filter out duplicates that will occur within short time frames.

Comment: @CBroe That's correct email is addressed to both recipients at the same time. It depends if the original email is `To: email.1@domain.com,email.2@domain.com` then it will be `To: email.1@gmail.com,email.2@gmail.com`, and if one of the emails CC/BCC it will be the same as the pipe detects it.

Answer (score 0):

Like Alex says, you should really just forward the emails - most MTAs provide a mechanism for re-writing the sender (which is fairly essential nowadays). I'd also suggest you stop using cpanel, and unless you have a particular fondness for, and skills in Exim try Postfix.

The MOST likely cause is that this is running on Linux (you didn't say) and that you are invoking the next step of the journey via PHP's "mail()" function (again, you didn't say) without rewriting the original headers. In such a scenario, your code is simply invoking the command `sendmail -t -i` which determins the recipient from the headers in the email. Conversely with SMTP, the recipient is provided by the nagotiation before the mail headers and body are sent.

Either rewrite the headers and continue to use `mail()` or submit the forwarded message via SMTP or write your own wrapper around (e.g.) /usr/bin/mail

Comment: Yes, the instance is running on Linux. PHPMailer is used to send the emails.

Comment: We tried to modify headers `from`, `return-path` and some other headers that contain the real sender email `sender@gmail.com` to `email@domain.com` but it didn't work SES detects the real sender and blocks the email.